# Xamarin - create an environment to view HTML files

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have only written PC programs using C#, .NET, and WinForms, and am new to app development.

I have written a program that uses HTML files (as a type of "form"), that will then be passed to an app, which can then be used to read/record data. I.e.

- On the PC, a user creates a HTML "form"
- This is loaded onto a mobile device (phone or tablet)
- The user can then open the app, and access each individual (or individual copies) a HTML form to read/record data.
- This is then transferred back to the PC, and stored.

Now, I'm not too concerned with the transfer between the PC/device, or the storage of the data, or any of that at this point. What I am concerned about is the ability to open/view these HTML files within a single app.

As the program has already been written using .NET and WinForms, it needs to be converted to be used on a mobile device, and I have chosen Xamarin for this purpose. However I only have limited knowledge of this package, so I am not sure if I can achieve this within a single app (i.e. without having to pass it to a separate app to view the HTML files).

So: is there an environment in Xamarin that I can use to view HTML files within my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xamarin.Forms` has a [WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/) class that you can use to display HTML content, so viewing the content is rarely an issue.

Interacting with the HTML content can sometimes be a bit tricky because of the links not conforming to what the app expects. But you can often solve these issues using the `WebView.Navigating` event handler that will allow you to catch and change the navigation behavior.

`Xamarin.Forms`'s [WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/) relies on the native [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/) (iOS) and [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) (Android) and `Xamarin.Forms` allows you to override the native *Renderers*. Overriding the native renderer will give you access to the native `WebView` with full flexibility.

You also have the possibility to completely ignore `Xamarin.Forms`'s [WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/) and write your own view using native views.

It would probably be smart to test your WinForms app on iOS using Safari and on Android using Chrome as they are using the same rendering engines that will be used in respectively [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/) (iOS) and [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) (Android)